# Overflow hidden - anchor links overflow the content

Tags: css

Content get overflowed hidden when navigating to previous comments, please see the links.

Example: 
http://justfortest.cba.pl/misc/index.html (full content displayed)
http://justfortest.cba.pl/misc/index.html#comment-3 (content is cut to anchor link)

I discovered that when I remove overflow: hidden; from .content>div then content is not overflowed, but then the design is destroyed: problem with background and too long div.

after removing overflow: hidden; (problem with div length and background).
justfortest.cba.pl/misc/index2.html#comment-3

Updated:

Here is the code for content part:

```
.content {padding: 40px 0; border-top: 5px solid #e3e4e6; border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8; background: url("images/bg.png");}
.content>div { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #d8d8d8; background: #fff;}
.main {float: left; overflow: hidden; width: 610px; margin-bottom: -5000px; padding: 15px 35px 5030px;}
.sidebar {float: right; width: 260px; margin-bottom: -5000px; padding: 15px 19px 5030px; border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8; background: #fafbfc;}
```

Could you please help with that problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi there Newbie1, and welcome to SO. Please, read this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code  and this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Hi, thanks for links, I couldn't add the image, because reputation greater than 10 is needed. I checked the html and style with w3c and there are no serious errors. I also updated the content in th question with the CSS code. Is there something more I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.main {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* from -5000px */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px 35px 30px; /* from 15px 35px 5030px */
  width: 610px;
}
```

Comment: Your 'margin-bottom: -5000px' seem to trow the page in some sort of a 'Pee-ka-boo' bug. Also, the DOM has trouble calculating the whole page height .. has you display from a specific anchor#hash.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but it doesn't help. There is still the same problem.

Comment: I replaced mine .main class into your .main class you put above.

Comment: but there was also 

`.sidebar {float: right; width: 260px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 15px 19px 5030px; border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8; background: #fafbfc;}`

I replaced into

`.sidebar {float: right; width: 260px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 15px 19px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8; background: #fafbfc;}`

and now seem to works fine:) Thank you for the solution. Can I give you + or smth to than you?

Comment: If you confirm it was that HUGE bottom padding, just +1 my first comment to indicate others your way to the solution.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it demands 10 reputation point, so I can't do this, but again many thanks for the help :)

Comment: +1 this fixed my issue. In my case margin-bottom:20000px was the problem.  So what the footer doesn't "stick" to the window bottom? for now I'll deal.